# Does not compile with cardview on Android Studio 3

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

Im using Android Studio 3 with AppCompat
It doesnt compile with this 3 labels:

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Here is my XML code i do not know what it could be wrong in my dependencies i do have the AppCompat and the CardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.valenzuela.salvador.apuebacalculo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/diferencial"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Calculo Diferencial"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#8c000000"
            android:textColor="#ffe3e3e3"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You have said it doesn't compile. Please provide any error messages and anything you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the "auto" namespace on this line:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

But you're trying to use it like this:

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

It doesn't matter which of these two you change, but they have to match. So you either need `xmlns:card_view` or `app:cardCornerRadius` etc. I recommend using the `app` name; that's standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

> Try adding this

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

> in your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" <--add this line -->
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.valenzuela.salvador.apuebacalculo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/diferencial"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Calculo Diferencial"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#8c000000"
            android:textColor="#ffe3e3e3"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```